# Python .after command not working

Tags: python

I am having trouble with my .after command. Instead of waiting 5 seconds, it is going to the next function instantly. How do I make it wait 5 seconds?

```
def passwordmaking():
    passmakingtext = ment1.get()
    if passmakingtext == passmaking:
        print ("pass")
        sys.exit()
    else :
        label.configure(text = "Password isn't right, Bye")
        label.after(5000, bye())
def bye():
    sys.exit()
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     label.after(5000, bye())
> ```

Is wrong; you're first calling `bye()`, then *would* call `label.after(arg1,arg2)` with `arg2` being the return value of `bye()`; however, since `bye()` kills your program, `label.after` never gets called.

You probably wanted  something like `arg2` representing a callable that gets called after 5000ms; in that case, use `bye` rather than `bye()`. One is the function object, the other the result of calling it.